# My code works through python shell, but not terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am trying to write a python script that works on a Raspberry PI and exchanges data between it and Arduino Uno by using `pyserial` library. The code is working through Arduino IDE Serial Monitor. I tried to write the same python commands into the Python3 shell and it worked. However, if I write `python3 my_script.py`, it doesn't work. I tried to write `python3` only to access the python shell, and then I wrote the same lines of code and it worked.

---

Edit #1:
I did not include the code because I don't think it is useful. However, This is a sample code of what I have wrote:

```py
import serial


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
ser.flush()
ser.write(b'SOME COMMAND\n')
response = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
print(response)
```

This code is working if I wrote it line by line in python shell, but not when calling it from the terminal by writing `python3 my_script.py`

Comment: Some code to debug would be nice. With what you have given us right now, all we can really say is that you got something wrong. For starters, we don't even know you saved your script in `my_script.py` and not some other file - or that it was actually python code at all.

Comment: @fredrik I did not include the code because I don't think it is useful. However, I edited my question. The code was working by the way, but suddenly it doesn't. I am sure that I saved my script in `my_script.py` because I can see the output of my print statements. The problem is with this line: `response = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()`, it doesn't get a response. It is an empty string.

Comment: How quickly does the Arduino respond to "SOME COMMAND"?  (You should be able to see any such delay in the Serial Monitor.)  The one obvious difference between running a script and entering commands manually is that the read would be performed much sooner in the first case, perhaps it's timing out before the reply is received.

Comment: If it suddenly stopped working I would guess that the device is no longer connected to `/dev/ttyACM0`. Check `dmesg` for which device node it is connected to.

Comment: @jasonharper It was working but suddenly it doesn't. There is no delay in `Serial Monitor`.

Comment: @fredrik I already checked that, and it is still connected. I can see it within Arduino IDE, too. Also, when I write the same lines of code within the python shell, it will work. Which means it is still connected because I am getting the response from Arduino.

Comment: Is the arduino ide open at the same time as you're running your script? If so, at least stop the serial monitor.

Comment: @fredrik No, it is closed. If it is opened, I will get an error when I try to execute my code through the python shell which is `port is already in use` or some similar error, I don't remember the exact error message.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is that the baudrate no longer matches (which would cause the card to not understand your command).

Comment: @fredrik The weird thing is that the code is working in python shell. The baudrate is the same in the Arduino code, the python script code and the python shell code. Everything is the same, everything is working properly in python shell and arduino serial monitor. If there is a problem in my code or the baudrate, it will not work if I tried to run my code in the python shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several fixes, it seems like something is buggy in my raspberry pi setup. I used `pyfirmata` which fixed my issue.